# Am I leaking memory here (Interpolation with GNU GSL)?

Tags: c++, pointers, gsl

I am using the GNU GSL library to do some interpolation.

```
double Interpolator::calculateInterpolant(const InterpTypes& TYPE)
{
    double interpolant;
    const int SIZE = predictor_.size();

    gsl_interp * interp = allocateInterpolationObject(TYPE, SIZE);
    gsl_interp_init(interp, &predictor_[0], &response_[0], SIZE);
    gsl_interp_accel * acc = gsl_interp_accel_alloc();
    interpolant = gsl_interp_eval(interp, &predictor_[0], &response_[0],  
        level_, acc);
    gsl_interp_free(interp);
    gsl_interp_accel_free(acc);
    return interpolant;
}
```

The function I am concerned with is `allocateInterpolationObject`.  Here is the body of that function:

```
gsl_interp * allocateInterpolationObject(const InterpTypes& TYPE, 
    const int& SIZE)
{
    gsl_interp * interp;
    switch (TYPE){
        case LINEAR:
            interp = gsl_interp_alloc(gsl_interp_linear, SIZE);
            break;
        case CSPLINE:
            interp = gsl_interp_alloc(gsl_interp_cspline, SIZE);
            break;
        case AKIMA:
            interp = gsl_interp_alloc(gsl_interp_akima, SIZE);
            break;
    }
    return interp;
}
```

I know I am leaking memory somewhere in my program and I suspect it may be here because I do not free the object `interp` inside the `allocateInterpolationObject` function (even though I free it in the `calculateInterpolant` function).  But how can I free something before returning it?  I am a "pointer novice" and I could use some advice or clarification here.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I am leaking memory somewhere in my program and I suspect…

… stop right there. Never try to work on things like this on a suspicion. You're usually wrong. Use a memory debugger to determine which allocation it is you're leaking, follow how the allocated object (and pointers to it) are passed around and at the moment where the last pointer is "dropped" add the free.

The go-to too for memory debugging is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Use it.

> But how can I free something before returning it?

You don't.

alloc / free is not something that must be balanced on a per-function scope level. The rule is, that everything that gets alloc-ed must be eventually free-ed, but when this should happen is up to you.